# Can I have multiple plugins per repo?

Tags: cordova-plugins

All the examples on plugins consist of a line like so:

> cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-network-information.git

Where there is some git repo that has `plugin.xml` in its root.

Can I have a repo set up to contain two plugins in separate sub folders and how would the command line look to add those plugins.

And/or can I specify which branch from git to pull in?